# Database design - Many tables with unique tags or one table with all of them?

Tags: mysql, database

I'm working on the database (MySQL) - car dealership. Since the product (car) has a lot of features and unique values (gearbox, model, manufacturer...), I wonder, how to create a well designed database for it.

Should I use:

```
Table cars
columns -> id, name, manufacturer, model, gearbox...
```

Or:

```
Table cars
columns -> id, name, manufacturer_id, gearbox_id...

Table manufacturers
columns -> id, name

Table gearbox
columns -> id, name
```

There are a lot of unique values as I mentioned and I think it's not good to store them again and again, but if I create a lot of tables + link them with link table to product table (car), there will be a lot of joins when I make a query to get all of the values.

And these are only few of them, there are much more values I need to store for every product in the database.

Comment: https://www.thoughtco.com/database-normalization-basics-1019735

Comment: Thank you OldProgrammer, but I have already researched a lot about normalization.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 options here:

1. You could store each car as a separate table and then have a row corresponding to the gearbox, etc.  This is awful, no one does it, don't do it.
2. You could serialize all the gearbox, etc. data as json strings and put them in your car cells.  This is also awful, some people have stupidly done this, but not that often.  Don't do it.
3. You could do things the normal, good way and implement separate tables for every class of object with foreign keys linking them.  This is the way to go.

Comment: I think I'd go with option 4.